# Is there a shortcut to typing each reserved_list[[i]] into an lm function in R?

Tags: r, lm

I have a reserved list. Each of these reserved lists correspond to an independent variable. Is there a short cut for the bolded part below.

To be clear, I need to find a way to write a short cut for:
lm(y~**res_list[[1]]+res_list[[2]]+res_list[[3]]+....+res_list[[10]]**

Comment: `lm(y ~ ., data = res_list)` should work assuming you want to include every list element. Note that if the list contains an element named `y` it will be used as the response variable, otherwise `y` will be taken from the environment the function is called in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use all of the elements of `res_list` (other than `y`, if `res_list` has an element named `y`), then @RitchieSacramento's suggestion

```r
lm(y ~ ., data = res_list)
```

should work. The semantics of `.` are documented in `?formula`.

Otherwise, you can always build your formula programmatically:

```r
f <- function(formula, index) {
  n <- length(formula)
  rhs <- formula[[n]]
  l <- lapply(index, function(i) bquote(.(rhs)[[.(i)]]))
  plus <- function(x, y) call("+", x, y)
  formula[[n]] <- Reduce(plus, l)
  formula
}

f(y ~ res_list, 1:10)
```

```
y ~ res_list[[1L]] + res_list[[2L]] + res_list[[3L]] + res_list[[4L]] + 
    res_list[[5L]] + res_list[[6L]] + res_list[[7L]] + res_list[[8L]] + 
    res_list[[9L]] + res_list[[10L]]
```

```r
f(hello ~ world, c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L))
```

```
hello ~ world[[1L]] + world[[2L]] + world[[3L]] + world[[5L]] + 
    world[[8L]]
```